# How do show/hide user control in design mode

Tags: c#, winforms, designmode

I'm working on a User control and I want to display it when in design mode a button has been selected and hide it  when this one lost the focus.

This is the property and when a button has been set

```
 public AnimatedButton MenuButton
 {
        get {
            return _ButtonOwner;
        }
        set {
            _ButtonOwner = value;
            this.Visible = this.DesignMode; //===>Set visible the panel when is in a design mode
            if (value != null) {
                _ButtonOwner.StateChange += new AnimatedButton.StateChangeHandler (_OwnerStateChangeEvent);              

            }
        }
    }
```

what I want is when I select a button on design mode a other control set visible and when I lost the focus on the button the other control set invisible.

I already commited the changes to git hub if you some one want to take look to the code. I have a PanelWindow Control and AnimatedButton control, in Panel window control has the property menu button type of AnimatedButton and I can select a animiate button from the form , and what I want is when the menu button has selected the panel window set visible and when this lost focus the panel window hides, all this only in the design mode U.U I hope you guys can understand

Comment: Set it in the default ctor?

Comment: From your code it isn't really clear what are you're looking for, what you tried, what achieved and what want to change.

Comment: when I select a button on design mode a other control set visible and when I lost the focus on the button the control set invisible

Comment: Can you in ctor check design mode and subscribe to the events? But I don't think it's worth to add so complex logic just for design time.

Comment: I already commited the changes to [git hub](https://github.com/MrAlex6204/GYMSystem/tree/master/GYMManager) if you want to take look to the code. I have a PanelWindow Control and AnimatedButton control, in Panel window control has the property menu button type of AnimatedButton and  I can select a animiate button from the form , and what I want is when the menu button has selected the panel window set visible and when this lost focus the panel window hides, all this only in the design mode U.U I hope you can understand my code

Comment: Visibility is, to my mind, a runtime state.  To hide something in the designer is just begging for trouble.

Comment: I know is silly what I want to do but just for the design mode but becauseit will be great if I could do this then  I can encapsulate the controls into a Assembly and  if I want to used I will just drag and drop the control configure. XD

Answer (score 1):

The design time environment does not take notice of your Visible property when deciding to show the control on the design surface. You can set the Visible property to whatever you like but it will still always show.

This is done so that you can still see and design a control that will be initially hidden when run.